# How can I transfer array values to another doing some calculations on the process?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create an array from another but not before I do some calculation for each item from the first array.

As you can see, I tried to use the function Aggregate from `System.Linq` to obtain in each item of the result array, the result of the item of first array + sum of previous values (i.e. `int[] value = {a, b, c, d)` - `int[] result = {a, a+b, a+b+c, a+b+c+d}`. However, the way that I used it didn't give me the expected results.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // First array
            int[] value = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

            // Result array with same Length of first one
            int[] result = new int[value.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
            {
                result[i] = value.Aggregate((sum, next) => sum + next);
                Console.WriteLine(result[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
// Output
{15, 15, 15, 15, 15}

// Expected output
1, 1+2=3, 3+3=6, 6+4=10, 10+5=15
{1, 3, 6, 10, 15}
```

At this program, I just tried to add the sum of previous values to the current value for each item of result because it is what I need at the moment. However, It'd be great if someone has a solution that allows me to do any kind of calculation before storing it in a new array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code would go through the array only once and the complexity is  O(n).

```
var sum = 0;
var results = values.Select(item => sum += item).ToArray();
```

Comment: How is the `sum` variable incrementing ?

Comment: In the select there is a +=

Comment: Sorry my bad... Nice answer then :-)

Comment: Notice the `sum+=item;`?

Comment: Thank you very much. It was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are each time evaluating the whole array, therefore ending up in the total sum each time. Add a call to the [Take](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.8) function so you will only add items up to your current item.

```
for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
{
    result[i] = value.Take(i + 1).Aggregate((sum, next) => sum + next);
    Console.WriteLine(result[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Another great way to achieve what I expected.